# SSD broken? GParted output

Tags: ssd, gparted

Note - before voting down, please suggest how to improve my question. Thanks.

The goal is to try to make my SSD work again. I would have formatted it using GParted, but a message "Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc" appears. If I check it with GParted, I get the following output. What to do next?

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2

Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sdc5  00:04:36    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sdc5  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdc5 (partition)
start: 35158016
end: 480663551
size: 445505536 (212.43 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sdc5 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:04:35    ( ERROR )

e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sdc5  00:04:35    ( ERROR )

/dev/sdc5: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway? yes


/dev/sdc5: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
e2fsck: Unknown code ____ 251 while recovering journal of /dev/sdc5
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sdc5

========================================

Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sdc1
========================================
```

Further, the "fsck" command gives:

```
fsck -c /dev/sdc1
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
/dev/sdc1: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? yes
fsck.ext4: Unknown code ____ 251 while recovering journal of /dev/sdc1
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sdc1


/dev/sdc1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

GSmartControl 0.8.7 gives no errors:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-8-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2KF256H6 SATA 256GB
Serial Number:    CVLT643301NS256HGN
LU WWN Device Id: 5 5cd2e4 14d23971b
Firmware Version: LBFD07N
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Sep  4 23:45:13 2018 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  15) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0039) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 257
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   088   088   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       271
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       219
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       942
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   091   091   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       60
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0033   095   095   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       26873
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0033   011   011   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       87
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0033   092   092   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       271
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   091   091   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       2754
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   090    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       135
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   035   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 10/51)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       579827802372
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
225 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       52506
226 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
227 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
228 Power-off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   091   091   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
236 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
238 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       52506
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       217489
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2413

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       219         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       219         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Erm, what do you want to do? Wipe the entire SSD and reformat it?  or just format `/dev/sdc5`?

Comment: @Fabby Try to make it work again, anyhow. The data is backuped.

Comment: I agree with below answer: You're trying to resurrect a zombie: not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
...
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0033   011   011   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       87
```

This value is just one step away from a SMART predictive failure indication. If the internet descriptions of this value are correct, this would mean that the worst chip on your SSD has 87 blocks that are already marked as unusable. Compared to attribute #179, it looks like this chip is responsible for almost one-third of the total bad blocks that have been replaced with spares so far.

(As far as I've understood, the RAW_VALUE is the actual value, and VALUE is that scaled so that bigger = better. When that attribute is no longer above the corresponding THRESHold value, a pre-failure SMART error is emitted.)

Together with that, the fact that you're seeing errors on write operations in `dmesg` suggests to me that this SSD is not well. It might not be technically dead yet, but that might not be far away.

Comment: Damn! I missed that!  **+1** Eagle-eyes!